# I need a proverb for one's absence in a function or place

Tags: phrase-request, proverbs

I need  a proveb for situation " when one person is absent in a function or city or institute. So we say it doesn't make any problem, if he is absent, still the function goes on. So which proverb is to be used for this situation.

Comment: Something along the lines of "life goes on" perhaps?

Comment: How about: No one is irreplaceable/indispensable.

Answer (score 2):

The most appropriate saying I can think of is borrowed from the theater:

> The show must go on.

It can be applied to anything really, as long as it's OK to (vaguely) imply that the action feels much like putting on a show.  For example:

> Well, we can't really do the ceremony without Dave here, but nevertheless, as they say, "the show must go on".  I guess we'll have to muddle through without him.